# Django, send response from two servers

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, django

The idea is that I'm sending data with ajax to my class view, when class view receives data it sends it to an external server, this server gives me a response that I display in my template view by success function in my ajax post method. It works awesome, no problem at all.

However, when my view gets POST request it also creates some data in my DataBase via module (it is for search history records). I save this data, then I want to get all this data and display it.

So, what I need is to return two sets of data, one is json for success function of my ajax method and another one from my database. I have no idea how to put them together, or how to send them separately... Is there any ideas?

**view class**

```
        user_id = request.session['user_id']

        jresponse = response.json()

        query = QueryHistory(userID = user_id, queryID = jresponse['query'], query = keyword)
        query.save()

        query_list = QueryHistory.objects.all()

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(jresponse), content_type="application/json")
```

**saerch.js**

```
 success : function(response) {
            $('#id_keyword').val(''); // remove the value from the input
            console.log(response); // log the returned json to the console
            if(response.hasOwnProperty('results')){
                for (var i = 0; i < response.results.length; i++){
                    $("#search-table").append("<tr><td>alldatagoeshere</td></tr>");
                }
            }

        // handle a non-successful response
        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
            $('#results').html("<div class='alert-box alert radius' data-alert>Oops! We have encountered an error: "+errmsg+
                " <a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>"); // add the error to the dom
            console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
        }
    });
```

**models**

```
class QueryHistory(models.Model) :
  userID = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  queryID = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  query = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

As you can see from my view class there are two different data sets, `jresponse` (from external server that works fine) and `query_list` that is from my own database (that should be added to `return HttpResponse(query_list , json.dumps(jresponse), content_type="application/json")`)

Comment: If you have both datasets already available when you return a response from your class view, why not put them into a list and send them both? `return HttpResponse(json.dumps([some_data, other_data])`

Comment: @AndréBorie thanks for your reply. In  this case i'm getting an error that <QueryHistory: QueryHistory object> is not JSON serializable

Comment: @AndréBorie just added serializers and everything works now, many thx for your help, it was really useful for me =)